# POST /api/mpesa/callbackurl 502 Bad Gateway in ngrok in mpesa integration

Tags: laravel, ngrok, mpesa

I am integrating Mpesa into my Laravel app. I have simulated a transaction where a user can make a payment successfully. After the payment I want the payment details to be stored in the database, through the callback URL. I have made an API route that calls the function which encodes and saves the data in the DB. I am using ngrok to tunnel my localhost to the callback URL. Whenever I execute the function in postman and successfully make the payment, I get an error on ngrok "**POST /api/mpesa/callbackurl    502 Bad Gateway**". I have researched and found it a server error but I have channeled the localhost well in ngrok..how can I fix this.

here is my stkpush function

```
public function stkpush(Request $request)
{
    $url='https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest';

    $curl_post_data=[
        'BusinessShortCode'=>174379,
        'Password'=>$this->lipanampesapassword(),
        'Timestamp'=>Carbon::rawParse('now')->format('YmdHms'),

        'TransactionType'=> "CustomerPayBillOnline",
        'Amount'=>1,
        'PartyA'=>254712345678,
        'PartyB'=>174379,
        'PhoneNumber'=>254712345678,
        'CallBackURL'=>'https://89af-196-202-210-53.eu.ngrok.io/api/mpesa/callbackurl',
        'AccountReference'=>'Waweru Enterprises',
        'TransactionDesc'=>'Paying for Products Bought'
    ];

    $data_string=json_encode($curl_post_data);

    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$this->newaccesstoken()));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);

    $curl_response=curl_exec($curl);
    return $curl_response;
}
```

the callback url route in the api.php

Route::post('/mpesa/callbackurl', [MpesatransactionController::class,'mpesaresponse'])->name('mpesaresponse');

the mpesa response function

```
public function mpesaresponse(Request $request)
{
    $response=$request->getContent();

    $transaction=new mpesatransaction;
    $transaction->response=json_encode($response);
    $transaction->save();

}
```

the ngrok panel
[image: ngrok panel]

Comment: Hey Stephen, did you find a solution to this

Comment: @RaymondGitonga not yet..i uploaded the project online instead of working it on localhost..i will get back to in a few days and find a solution,but if you have a solution post it here it can help others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You entered the wrong address on the ngrok terminal. You entered `ngrok http 127.0.0.1:8000:80` as from the image uploaded.

The correct syntax should be `ngrok http 127.0.0.1:8000` without the `:80` port.

Answer (score 3):

To tunnel all request to ngrok you have to specify the following. Rewrite all requests to your domain

```
ngrok http {localhost}:{port} --host-header=rewrite {localhost}:{port}
```

This will make sure all requests are re-written to your local domain

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the your callback URL in your function to read as follows:

```
public function stkpush(Request $request)
{
    $url='https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest';

    $curl_post_data=[
        ...
        'CallBackURL'=>'https://89af-196-202-210-53.eu.ngrok.io/api/mpesaresponse',
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if these tunnelling urls prove hard to work with, you can use a public requestbin [here](https://public.requestbin.com/r/enob0vx6o5e) which works well with Safaricom's sandbox environment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34381307)